# l2tp vpn Ubuntu 22.04

Tags: 20.04, network-manager, 22.04, ipsec, l2tp

I've gotten a new laptop and upgraded to 22.04, but I can no longer seem to get the l2tp/ip-sec VPN required for my job working anymore. I'm using the Gnome NetworkManager to configure this (just like the old system) and I do successfully "connect" and receive an IP address, but I can't seem to ping anything on the destination network.

I still have my old install, so I connected to the VPN on both laptops and pasted the output of "ip a" and "ip route show" below just to compare. I do see one difference in the "ip a" command (shown below), but I'm not sure what I need to do to get them to match or if it's even the problem...

**Old**

```
13: ppp0: <POINTOPOINT,MULTICAST,NOARP,UP,LOWER_UP> mtu 1400 qdisc fq_codel state UNKNOWN group default qlen 3
link/ppp 
inet 192.168.50.6/32 scope global noprefixroute ppp0
   valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever
```

**New**

```
7: ppp0: <POINTOPOINT,MULTICAST,NOARP,UP,LOWER_UP> mtu 1400 qdisc fq_codel state UNKNOWN group default qlen 3
    link/ppp 
    inet 192.168.50.3 peer 216.83.74.140/32 scope global ppp0
       valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever
    inet 192.168.50.3/32 scope global noprefixroute ppp0
       valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever
```

**Old**

```
default via 192.168.86.1 dev wlp0s20f3 proto dhcp metric 600 
169.254.0.0/16 dev virbr0 scope link metric 1000 linkdown 
172.17.0.0/16 dev docker0 proto kernel scope link src 172.17.0.1 linkdown 
172.18.0.0/16 dev br-c395aa5e5b48 proto kernel scope link src 172.18.0.1 
192.168.1.0/24 via 192.168.50.1 dev ppp0 proto static metric 50 
192.168.10.0/24 via 192.168.50.1 dev ppp0 proto static metric 50 
192.168.13.0/24 via 192.168.50.1 dev ppp0 proto static metric 50 
192.168.50.1 dev ppp0 proto static scope link metric 50 
192.168.86.0/24 dev wlp0s20f3 proto kernel scope link src 192.168.86.43 metric 600 
192.168.86.1 dev wlp0s20f3 proto static scope link metric 600 
192.168.122.0/24 dev virbr0 proto kernel scope link src 192.168.122.1 linkdown 
216.83.74.140 via 192.168.86.1 dev wlp0s20f3 proto static metric 600
```

**New**

```
default via 192.168.86.1 dev wlp0s20f3 proto dhcp metric 600 
169.254.0.0/16 dev virbr0 scope link metric 1000 linkdown 
172.17.0.0/16 dev docker0 proto kernel scope link src 172.17.0.1 linkdown 
192.168.1.0/24 via 192.168.50.1 dev ppp0 proto static metric 50 
192.168.10.0/24 via 192.168.50.1 dev ppp0 proto static metric 50 
192.168.13.0/24 via 192.168.50.1 dev ppp0 proto static metric 50 
192.168.50.1 dev ppp0 proto static scope link metric 50 
192.168.86.0/24 dev wlp0s20f3 proto kernel scope link src 192.168.86.43 metric 600 
192.168.86.1 dev wlp0s20f3 proto static scope link metric 50 
192.168.122.0/24 dev virbr0 proto kernel scope link src 192.168.122.1 linkdown 
216.83.74.140 dev ppp0 proto kernel scope link src 192.168.50.3 
216.83.74.140 via 192.168.86.1 dev wlp0s20f3 proto static metric 50
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's a routing bug since NetworkManager 1.36. Try deleting the spurious route that has no metric with :

```
sudo ip addr del 192.168.50.3 peer 216.83.74.140 dev ppp0
```

The upstream NetworkManager bug report is :

- https://gitlab.freedesktop.org/NetworkManager/NetworkManager/-/issues/946#note_1406609

Related NetworkManager-l2tp bug report:

- https://github.com/nm-l2tp/NetworkManager-l2tp/issues/132#issuecomment-1155098198

Comment: That was it - thank you very much.